# Excel Macro - Copy specific cells based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a way to copy specific data from an excel sheet through a macro. I've been doing a lot of google & youtube searching but am coming up short.

[image]

I need all numbers starting with 9 from column A.

The product name from column B - this should ignore cells with G

```
Street VIC & C Street NSW
```

The 4 cell values (including 0's) to the right of the Total: cell

This data should be placed in one row on a separate sheet in the same document.

So for example:

```
9343907003122     PANEL 15W     
Location1         G Street VIC   18  0  0  18
                  Total:         18  0  0  18
```

Should end up looking like:

```
9343907003122     PANEL 15W      18  0  0  18
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming numbers are in column A on Sheet1 and single lines written to Sheet2.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub mymacro()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iOutRow As Long
    iOutRow = 0

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    iLastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A" & iLastRow)

        If cell.Value Like "9###########" Then ' 12 digit starting 9

            iOutRow = iOutRow + 1
            cell.Resize(1, 2).Copy wsOut.Cells(iOutRow, 1)

        ElseIf LCase(cell.Offset(0, 1)) Like "total*" Then

            cell.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 4).Copy wsOut.Cells(iOutRow, 3)

        End If

    Next

    MsgBox iOutRow & " rows created on " & wsOut.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```